# How is the nasal secretion system of local immunity coupled with lymphatic circulation?

Tags: lymphatic-system, nose, immunity

I started a thread about *Nasal chronic Inflammation after influenza virus* [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17325/nasal-chronic-inflammation-after-influenza-virus).
However, I do not understand enough well the structure of the nose to answer the questions there.

I know that the lysed DNA (proteins) of small bronchial tree are circulated on the nasal epithelium.
I am not sure how this happens but my intuition is

- first through lymphatic circulation
- then on posterior nasalis membrane upward progression on the nasal membrane in the nares.

Picture about the nasal membrane.

[image]

Better pictures about the linkage of lymphatic circulation from the small bronchial trees into posterior nasal membrane are wanted.

However, I am not completely sure how this organisation occurs.

**How is the nasal secretion system of local immunity (IgA) coupled with the lymphatic circulation around the back of the nose?**

Comment: *I know that the lysed DNA (proteins) of small bronchial tree are circulated on the nasal epithelium*: Do you have a reference for this ?

Comment: @WYSIWYG Thank you for your question! This sentence was introduced by one leading researcher in the field last year in London. I contacted him about your question. I hope I can provide it to you.